# Using chained xpath expressions to extract parent node

Tags: xpath, css-selectors

I want to extract both key names and values from the following HTML.

```
<ul>
    <li><span class="label">Key A:</span> Value A
    </li>
</ul>
<td>
    <span class="label">Key B:</span> Value B
</td>
```

My strategy is to zoom into `span.label` directly to get the key, then zoom out to extract value from parent text. However, using the following xpath selectors, I am not able to extract the parent text successfully, even though `//span[@class="label"]/parent::*/text()` produced the right matches in Google Chrome.

```
        for field in section.css('span.label'):
            key = field.xpath('./text()').get().strip()
            value = field.xpath('./parent::*/text()').get().strip()
            section_fields[key]=value
```

Did I make a mistake with chained expressions?

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

```
import lxml.html as lh

label = """[your html above]"""

doc = lh.fromstring(label)
for l in doc.xpath('//span[@class="label"]'):
    print(l.text.strip(),l.tail.strip())
```

Output:

```
Key A: Value A
Key B: Value B
```

Answer (score -1):

Well, you should fix your XPath for :

```
./parent::*/text()[normalize-space()]
```

to ignore whitespace nodes. Or you can use more directly :

```
./following::text()[1]
```

Piece of code :

```
data = """<ul>
    <li><span class="label">Key A:</span> Value A
    </li>
</ul>
<td>
    <span class="label">Key B:</span> Value B
</td>"""

import lxml.html
tree = lxml.html.fromstring(data)

key=[]
value=[]
for field in tree.xpath('//span'):
    key.append(field.xpath('./text()')[0].strip())
    value.append(field.xpath('./parent::*/text()[normalize-space()]')[0].strip())

table=(list(zip(key,value)))

for a,b in table:
    print(a,b)
```

Output :

```
Key A: Value A
Key B: Value B
```